# Custom resize of borderless window in a PowerShell Windows Forms script

Tags: winforms, powershell, resize

I have a border-less Windows Forms window in my PowerShell script:

- I want the user to be able to resize it, but it should only **horizontally grow to the left**.
- The right border of the window needs to stay in its original place at all times.

The resizing itself works, but the window moves horizontally during the resizing. Also, every time I start resizing, the window jumps to the left or right once.

*As the original script is quite large, I made an example that shows the problem:*

```
# Custom resize example
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

$Form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form1.size = "500,500"
$Form1.FormBorderStyle = "None"
$Form1.TopMost = $true
$Form1.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form1.add_MouseClick({
    if ($_.Button -eq "Right") {
        $form1.close()
    }
})

$resizeBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$resizeBar.BackColor = "150,150,150"
$resizeBar.Size = "8,500"
$resizeBar.Cursor = "SizeWE"
$Form1.controls.add($resizeBar)

$resizeBar.add_MouseDown({ $ResizeTimer.start()})
$resizeBar.add_MouseUp({ $ResizeTimer.stop()})

$comp = new-object System.ComponentModel.Container
$ResizeTimer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer($comp)
$ResizeTimer.Interval = 10

$ResizeTimer.add_Tick({
    $MousePosX =  ([System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position).x
    $Form1_LeftPos = $Form1.Left

    if ($lastmx -eq 0) {
        $script:lastmx = $MousePosX
    }
    $diffX =  $MousePosX - $lastmx

    $Form1.width = ($Form1.width - $diffX)
    $Form1.Left = $Form1_LeftPos - $diffX
    $script:lastmx = $MousePosX
})

$Form1.showdialog()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of small issues:

- Initialize your `$script:lastmx` variable to 0.
- Always refer to it as `$script:lastmx`, not `$lastmx`.
- The line `$Form1.Left = $Form1_LeftPos - $diffX` should actually read `$Form1.Left = $Form1_LeftPos + $diffX`

This together works for me:

```psh
$script:lastmx = 0
$ResizeTimer.add_Tick({
    $MousePosX = ([System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position).x
    $Form1_LeftPos = $Form1.Left
    if ($Script:lastmx -eq 0) {
        $script:lastmx = $MousePosX
    }
    $diffX = $MousePosX - $Script:lastmx
    $Form1.width = ($Form1.width - $diffX)
    $Form1.Left = $Form1_LeftPos + $diffX
    $script:lastmx = $MousePosX
})
```